# problems when uploading multiple image on firebase via firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

That's the code with the error

"ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'getDownloadURL' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png'). (storage/invalid-root-operation)"

````js
    submitAtleteData(name, surname) {
    
    var name = this.selectedImage.name;
    var name1 = this.selectedImage1.name1;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(name);
    const fileRef1 = this.storage.ref(name1);
    const img1 = this.storage.upload(name, this.selectedImage)
    const img2 =this.storage.upload(name1, this.selectedImage1)

    img1.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
          this.url = url;
        })
      })
    ).subscribe();

    img2.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        fileRef1.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url1) => {
          this.url1 = url1;
          alert('complete');
        })
      })
    ).subscribe();

    this.upload.AddAtleta(name, surname,  this.url, this.url1);
   
  };

   selectedImage: any = null;

   showPreview(event1: any) {
    this.selectedImage = event1.target.files[0];
  }

  selectedImage1: any = null;

  showPreview1(event2: any) {
   this.selectedImage1 = event2.target.files[0];
 }

  

}```
````

Comment: Have you tried changing `fileRef` to `const fileRef = this.storage.ref().child(name);` and same for fileRef1?

Comment: yea, it gives me this error "ERROR TypeError: childPath.split is not a function"